# ISR documentation with doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen, microcontroller, isr

I have some ISR's and I do not really know how to documentate them by doxygen.
 Do you have an idea?

Here an example. Is there any special code by doxygen to documentate this?

```
ISR(usartTimer_OVF_vect){
    usartData.flag_send_data = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly it is not possible as it is not valid C, but with workaround it could be possible.

```
#if defined(__DOXYGEN__)
void usartTimer_OVF_Vect(void)
#else
ISR(usartTimer_OVF_vect)
#endif
{
    usartData.flag_send_data = TRUE;
}
```

In this case, doxygen will simply see a void function with `usartTImer_OVF_Vect` name without any parameters.